# PHP - Generate unique ID in order in folder

Tags: php, image, apache, file

My code upload an image inside a folder on a local Apache server. I want to be able to give a unique ID to every image, but in order in the folder. This is very important.

I want something like this : UserImage1, UserImage2, UserImage3,..... UserImage254... UserImage8888.

I will never have a million images. It is only for an event of 3 days.

For now I am using uniqid and I'm not sure if it is what I need. This is my code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
   

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0){
            if($fileSize < 50000000){
                $unique_id = time() . mt_rand();
                $fileNameNew = uniqid($prefix="userimage", false).".".$fileActualExt;
                //fileNameNew = strval($unique_id).".".$fileActualExt;

                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);

                header('Location: index.php?uploadsucess');
            } else{
                echo "Le fichier que vous tenté d'ajouter est trop volumineux";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Une erreur est survenue. Veuillez réessayer";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Vous ne pouvez pas ajouter un fichier de ce format";
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want incremental numbering like that you must keep track of that number somehow. You can derrive it from the filename of the last file upload or use other means to store the id (file, db, w/e).

Comment: Thanks for the idea it worked. I got the latest filename convert it in int and add 1. Like 1.jpg, 2,jpg, 3.jpg.

Comment: Or just append a PHP [TIME STAMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) to the file name ..  It's guaranteed to be in chronological order .. And nothing to "figure out"  `echo "UserImage-" . time();`

Comment: And, if you expect more than one image per second uploaded .. You can use [Micro Time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Comment: @Zak has a valid point in case you have high traffic. The file number might be read by the system for more than one request and you'll end up overriding all others.

Comment: Yes it is risky right now, I will implement that practice for sure to avoid frustration with the app. Thanks